# pcie passthrough in libvert failing through port multiplier, unknown header type 127

Tags: qemu, virtualization, pci-e, google-coral

Trying to use 4x pcie Coral TPU accelerators(for object and voice recognition in home assistant) through a pcie port multiplier board(convert a 4x slot into four 1x slots)
Without the multiplier board they pass through and function as expected.
When using the multiplier board I'm getting the following error.

"Error starting domain: internal error: Unknown PCI header type '127' for device '0000:29:00.0'"

I'm adding the devices through virt-managers GUI and getting the error when trying to start the VM.

Using QEMU for virtualization on an AMD Ryzen 9 5900X on an AsRock X570D4U.
Virtualization, iommu, is enabled in bios and working on the host machine.
Host is running Debian 11, tried guests of debian 10 11 and windows.
I have tried both Q35 and i440FX chipset's in the VM.

Multiplier board is [Link](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/313763215654)
Also using these adapters but as they work without above multiplier I don't think they are the issue [Link](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/134198160402)

Below from host machine, 29 is through the multiplier, 32 is directly on a pcie 4x slot.

```
root@DC:~# lspci -t
-[0000:00]-+-00.0
           +-00.2
           +-01.0
           +-01.2-[20-31]----00.0-[21-31]--+-01.0-[23]----00.0
           |                               +-03.0-[25-2a]----00.0-[26-2a]--+-01.0-[27]--
           |                               |                               +-03.0-[28]--
           |                               |                               +-05.0-[29]----00.0
           |                               |                               \-07.0-[2a]--
           |                               +-04.0-[2b]----00.0
           |                               +-05.0-[2c]----00.0
           |                               +-06.0-[2d-2e]----00.0-[2e]----00.0
           |                               +-08.0-[2f]--+-00.0
           |                               |            +-00.1
           |                               |            \-00.3
           |                               +-09.0-[30]----00.0
           |                               \-0a.0-[31]----00.0
           +-02.0
           +-03.0
           +-03.2-[32]----00.0
           +-04.0
           +-05.0
           +-07.0
           +-07.1-[33]----00.0
           +-08.0
           +-08.1-[34]--+-00.0
           |            +-00.1
           |            +-00.3
           |            \-00.4
           +-14.0
           +-14.3
           +-18.0
           +-18.1
           +-18.2
           +-18.3
           +-18.4
           +-18.5
           +-18.6
           \-18.7
root@DC:~# lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex [1022:1480]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU [1022:1481]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:01.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge [1022:1483]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:03.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge [1022:1483]
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:05.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:07.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:07.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] [1022:1484]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1482]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] [1022:1484]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0 [1022:1440]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1 [1022:1441]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2 [1022:1442]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3 [1022:1443]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4 [1022:1444]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5 [1022:1445]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6 [1022:1446]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7 [1022:1447]
20:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Switch Upstream [1022:57ad]
21:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a3]
21:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a3]
21:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a3]
21:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a3]
21:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a3]
21:08.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a4]
21:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a4]
21:0a.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:57a4]
23:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
25:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1184e PCIe Switch Port [1b21:1184]
26:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1184e PCIe Switch Port [1b21:1184]
26:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1184e PCIe Switch Port [1b21:1184]
26:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1184e PCIe Switch Port [1b21:1184]
26:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1184e PCIe Switch Port [1b21:1184]
**29:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Global Unichip Corp. Coral Edge TPU [1ac1:089a] (rev ff)**
2b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1533] (rev 03)
2c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1533] (rev 03)
2d:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge [1a03:1150] (rev 04)
2e:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family [1a03:2000] (rev 41)
2f:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
2f:00.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller [1022:149c]
2f:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller [1022:149c]
30:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 51)
31:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 51)
**32:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Global Unichip Corp. Coral Edge TPU [1ac1:089a]**
33:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
34:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
34:00.1 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP [1022:1486]
34:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller [1022:149c]
34:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
```

XML from VM

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x29" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
  </source>
  <rom bar="on"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x0b" function="0x0"/>
</hostdev>
```

I tried adding the whole multiplier board into the VM manually as it does not show in the GUI as an option but don't really have any idea what I'm doing there. Past that this is way beyond my understanding now, any guidance or suggestions to test would be great.